# Flatten an ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to flatten an ExpandableListView in Android? I have an ExpandableListView, and when a user searches for a specfic string therein, I want to not show the groups, but show all the children that match the search string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapter, return an empty view. This will prevent the group view from displaying:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return new View(parentActivity);
}
```

In the ExpandableListView, expand all the groups:

```
int count = adapter.getGroupCount();
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    listView.expandGroup(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be **TWO** ways:

**[1]** Take another one listview(hiddden by default) in your XML for searching-match result show, when search happens, **hide ExpandableListView** and **Set Visibility = VISIBLE Another Hidden Simple ListView**

But, in this way, you have to put somethink button like OK, when user has seen searched List, by pressing OK it can see ExpandableListView.

**[2]** You can set custom row of **CHILD CLASS** to set **Left MARGIN  =  --10dp(or something needed)** when searched result is shown. You also have to use **FLAG** at time of search. And in adapter by checking this FLAG have to set left margin of textview.

---

**EDIT  3rd WAY**

---

**[3]** If flag is setted, fill GROUP-LIST with SEARCHED item.  Take another Extra Blank-List and  **fill Child-List with Blank-List**.

In this way Left Margin not needed to set.

Comment: I've considered doing that, but I am hoping for something simpler. You said there may be two ways. Which is the other way?

Comment: So #2 would show the children on the same level as the groups, but it still shows the groups. Is there any way besides #1 to hide the groups?

Comment: If searched, then FLAG will be setted, if FLAG is setted make the GROUP-LIST BLANK( **or take another extra BLANK-LIST** )and fill Group with this blank list.

Comment: As INDIAN time, this is too late night, I am leaving, just post your Try and Result. I will See tomorrow. Well, Good-Knight.

Comment: Thanks Chintan. I found a better way to do it. I posted my own answer.